# Creating Swift AVAudioPlayer error

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

Trying to add multiple players using the code below:

```
class AVAudioPlayerPool: NSObject {

class func playerWithURL(url : NSURL) -> AVAudioPlayer? {
    let availablePlayers = players.filter { (player) -> Bool in return   player.playing == false && player.url == url
}
    if let playerToUse = availablePlayers.first {
        print("Reusing player for \(url.lastPathComponent)")
        return playerToUse
    }
    var error : NSError?

    if let newPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL:url, error: &error){
        print("Creating new player for url \(url.lastPathComponent)")
        players.append(newPlayer)
        return newPlayer
    }
    else{
        print("Couldn't load \(url.lastPathComponent):\(error)")
        return nil
    }


 }
}
```

but I keep getting an error "Argument labels '(contentsOfURL:, error:)' do not match any available overloads" coming from this line code "if let newPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL:url, error: &error)" I've attempted to use try! but I have not been able to do away with the error just receive a different error when I insert the "try!" any help would more than appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL:url, error: &error)` is not a valid constructor for AVAudioPlayer in Swift. Instead, you have to use `AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL:url)`, which can throw an error. There are multiple ways to handle the error (see [Swift Error Handling](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html)), but you probably want `try?`.

```
if let newPlayer = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url) {
    print("Creating new player for url \(url.lastPathComponent)")
    players.append(newPlayer)
    return newPlayer
} else {
    print("Couldn't load \(url.lastPathComponent):\(error)")
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Nice, thanks a lot I read the Swift Error Handling never thought to use try? was stuck on using the try! Thank You very Much!